# How to get slug value from array of objetcs if match with provide id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, methods

I'm trying to get the **slug** value from the array if inside the **object.extra.services** array, one of the element makes match with the id im providing...

```
// Service ID provided
const serviceID = '5cdd7c55f5abb90a689a44be';

// Array of services Ids
getProductsServices(products) {
      const productsServices = [
        ...new Set(products.map(product => product.extra.services))
      ];
      const productsList = [].concat.apply([], productsServices);
      return productsList;
    },

// ServiceId Matching
serviceMatch(serviceID) {
      return this.getProductsServices.includes(serviceID);
    }
```

Now i need to get the slug value inside the array that match the service id provided.

```
products [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0257dcbe760674b10d4122"),
    "desc" : "Diseño de Pagina Web",
    "extra" : {
        "image" : "/2018/06/diseño-de-logos-para-empresas.jpg",
        "services" : [ 
            "5cdd7c55f5abb90a689a44be", 
            "5cdd7c55f5abb90a689a3fcc", 
            "5cdd7c55f5abb90a689a3f42"
        ]
    },
    "name" : "Diseño de logo",
    "slug" : "diseno-de-logotipos-online"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0257dcbe760674b10d4122"),
    "desc" : "Diseño de logo",
    "extra" : {
        "image" : "/2018/06/diseño-de-logos-para-empresas.jpg",
        "services" : [ 
            "5cdd7c55f5abb90a689a44be", 
            "5cdd7c55f5abb90a689a3fcc", 
            "5cdd7c55f5abb90a689a3f42"
        ]
    },
    "name" : "Diseño de logo",
    "slug" : "diseno-de-logotipos-online"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0257dcbe760674b10d4122"),
    "desc" : "Diseño de Interior",
    "extra" : {
        "image" : "/2018/06/diseño-de-logos-para-empresas.jpg",
        "services" : [ 
            "5cdd7c55f5abb90a689a44be", 
            "5cdd7c55f5abb90a689a3fcc", 
            "5cdd7c55f5abb90a689a3f42"
        ]
    },
    "name" : "Diseño de logo",
    "slug" : "diseno-de-logotipos-online"
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **includes**:

```
const found = products.find(product => product.extra.services.includes("5cdd7c55f5abb90a689a3fcc"))
if (found) {
  console.log('found', found)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you can achieve it using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) along with [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
const product = productsList.find(product => product.extra.services.some(id => id === serviceID))
console.log(product.slug)
```

Comment: Great this worked like a charm with some change to addapted to my work, Namaste my friend... hope your path in life gets more brighter!!